# Android TV emulator Internet connectivity issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tv

I have an android tv project. I run it over android tv emulator. The emulator has Internet connection but I couldnt ping a website.

Comment: do You open your website using WebView inside app ? AFAIK, Android TV doesn't support any web browser, so if You open your website in browser, it won't work.

Comment: Although there is internet connection on the emulator, I couldnt ping a website. Even I tried to ping my host over adb shell but for nothing. I need this step because in my project I should login in my cloud so I must test that there is connectivity to my cloud.